# SI function with vb.net

Tags: excel, wpf, vb.net, excel-formula

I'm writing a program that automaticly generates a pre-completed Excel file for my company. All is working fine, except a line where I'd like to write the following function :
=SI(F15="";"";G15-G15-0,5)

I tried two solutions :

first, this one :

```vb
Private Const quote As String = Chr(34)

'Code working fine

With .Range("H15")
   .Characters.Font.Size = 10
   .HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter
   .Formula = "=SI(F15=" & quote & quote & ";" & quote & quote & ";G15-F15-0,5)"
End With
```

which returns me the following exception :

```
L'exception System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException n'a pas été gérée
  ErrorCode=-2146827284
  HResult=-2146827284
  Message=Exception de HRESULT : 0x800A03EC
  Source=""
  StackTrace:
       à System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData& msgData)
       à Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range.set_Formula(Object )
       à AutoFHT.DocumentFHT..ctor() dans C:\Users\BOUCKB\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\AutoFHT\AutoFHT\DocumentFHT.vb:ligne 295
       à AutoFHT.MainWindow.BT_Test_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) dans C:\Users\BOUCKB\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\AutoFHT\AutoFHT\MainWindow.xaml.vb:ligne 5
       à System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
       à System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
       à System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
       à System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)
       à System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
       à System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
       à System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
       à System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseLeftButtonUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
       à System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
       à System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
       à System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
       à System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
       à System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)
       à System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
       à System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
       à System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
       à System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
       à System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
       à System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
       à System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
       à System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
       à System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
       à System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
       à System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
       à System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
       à System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       à System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       à MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       à MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
       à System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       à System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
       à System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       à MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       à MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
       à System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
       à System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
       à System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
       à System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
       à System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
       à System.Windows.Application.Run()
       à AutoFHT.Application.Main()
       à System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       à System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       à Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       à System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       à System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       à System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       à System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       à System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Then, I tried this one, which sets the formula with a space instead of the equals, and then remplaces the space with an equals :

```vb
Private Const quote As String = Chr(34)
Private Const egal As String = Chr(61)

'Code working fine

With .Range("H15")
   .Characters.Font.Size = 10
   .HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter
   .Formula = " SI(F15=" & quote & quote & ";" & quote & quote & ";G15-F15-0,5)"
   .Characters(0, 1).text = egal
End With
```

This one is almost working, but when I open the excel file, the formulas show up as text on the cells, and are not executed as formulas unless I press F2 and then Enter on the cell.

I tried to use this at the end on the with :

```vb
.Select
Forms.SendKeys.Send("{F2}")
Forms.SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")
```

but as Excel runs in background, it doesn't work.

Anyone could help me to solve this problem and get a fully working sheet ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure about `vb.net` but in `VBA` you need to put en-US formulas no matter the locale because `VBA` is simply `en_us` natively. It will transform the formula in your cell to your locale automatically, meaning the formula entered in `VB` should be: `=IF(F15="","",G15-G15-0.5)` Notice the comma instead of semicolon and a dot instead of a comma.

Comment: Thank you, you just solved my problem. I should have thought about that !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, the problem is that `VB` is en_US based, so no matter the locale you should write en_US formulas, meaning that you should input:

```
=IF(F15="","",G15-G15-0.5)
```

In code:

```
.Formula = "=IF(F15=" & quote & quote & "," & quote & quote & ",G15-F15-0.5)"
```

Notice the comma instead of semicolon and a dot instead of a comma. The output will be automatically translated into your locale.